# Open and Close the same window on the same button click

Tags: c#, xaml

On my MenuItem at the moment I open up a Window. Then if the person chooses to click on that MenuItem again, I need the Window that was open to close.

Then obviously, if they click it the third time it will open and so fourth.

**XAML**

```
<MenuItem x:Name="btnHelp" Click="btnHelp_Click" Foreground="#FF7E8385" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18" Margin="110,10,0,0" Height="30" Width="70" Style="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Hand"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void btnHelp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    xamlHelp help = new xamlHelp();
    help.Show();
}
```

Comment: Just test whether the window is currently showing and act accordingly.

Comment: Move your reference to `xamlHelp` to the class level (outside the handler). Then, just check whether the window is visible and toggle it in the handler.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the information, I think your comment was replicated in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to have the variable be an instance field, rather than a local variable, so it can be accessed between calls.  At that point just close it if it exists, and recreate/show it if it doesn't:

```
private xamlHelp help = null;
private void btnHelp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (help != null)
    {
        help.Close();
        help = null;
    }
    else
    {
        help = new xamlHelp();
        help.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this creates a new `xamlHelp` every time. Wouldn't it be easier to show/hide the same instance?

Comment: @rae1 He could do that instead if he wanted.  It would be almost identical in terms of work, possibly a bit more work to show/hide, and also very possibly undesirable from a user interaction and resource consumption perspective.  However in the question he specifically said closing, not hiding, so that's what this did.

Comment: Just curious, why would it be undesirable from a user interaction and resource consumption perspective?

Comment: @Servy Thanks for your answer, Sorry for the misconfusion with Hiding and Closing etc .. I did want it to close.

Comment: @rae1 It depends on what's in it, but it may well make sense for it to be "reset".  As for resource consumption, I'd think that would be obvious; having a bunch of windows sitting around hidden consumes resources when they could instead be closed.

Comment: Got it. I got the impression of it would be better to keep it "hidden" to avoid creating a new instance every time; but I understand what you are saying... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of whether the help is currently showing and show/hide based on that,

```
private xamlHelp help = new xamlHelp();
private bool showingHelp = false;
private void btnHelp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (showingHelp)
    {
        help.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        help.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this would work aswell, but I don't want the data on the form to just hide, I need it to close. Thanks for your help.